# APA 6th Edition Reference Problem

Tags: cross-referencing, apa-style

I have a problem in giving reference in APA 6th style. My reference code as below. The problem is that in reference section, there is no numbering, and on url reference, there is blue square. Another one is that the section name is Bibliography rather than Reference, and text is not aligned either centered or flush left. How can I give proper reference section and change the name of reference section

```
\documentclass[chaparabic,ceng,phd,12pt,oneandhalf]{metu}

\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{xy} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[natbibapa,square]{apacite}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{figure}
\newcommand{\tab}{\hspace*{2em}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{apacite} 

\bibliography{thesis_references}


\appendix
\chapter{Appendix Name}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The document class `metu.cls` appears not be distributed with either TeXlive or MikTeX -- where might it be obtained from? Incidentally, it's usually a good idea to load the `hyperref` package last (or almost last) in the preamble.

Comment: metu.cls was created by me and it contains some thesis writing principle that applicable to our university. Also, I didnt get how to load hyperref

Comment: You have to load `hyperref` as the last package, with a few exceptions (among which `cleverref`).

Comment: Is the class relevant to the problem? If so, we need to see why. If not, use `report` or what ever instead in your example.

Comment: [Crosspost](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=92721#p92721)

Comment: It would be best if the community could have access to `metu.cls` in order to replicate the problem. Without communication from the author, I'm voting to close as unclear.